# Can't we say "It is likely to rain "

Tags: sentence-construction

Can't we say " Look at those dark clouds.It is **likely/bound/due to rain** " ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can indeed say "It's likely/bound to rain". *Bound* expresses a greater degree of certainty than *likely*.

We are more likely to use *due* if we are thinking of a previous weather report than if we are looking at clouds. The word suggest that something has been scheduled.

Comment: @ Thank you tunny ! I love your answers :)  Actually my question is about " it is likely + to infinitive " pattern that I have learnt we cant use likely in this way but I figured out that this sentence is special exception because "it" in " it is likely to rain " is almost weather I mean  "it" functions as a noun..

Comment: @Murat Forgive me, but when exactly does "it" not function as a noun?

Comment: I mean when we say " it is likely to rain "

Comment: How about this sentence?
"It is likely to appeal to a lot of people. I think it will sell fast."

Comment: @Murat. Where did you read that we can't use "It is likely + to infinitive"?

Comment: @ tunny I read it on my grammar book..and some reliable resources support that..                                                http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/likely-and-unlikely

Comment: @Murat. In the page you linked us two there are several examples of 'it is likely to ...'. Only the section at the bottom tells you that this is not possible *sometimes*, and explains that it cannot be used in the same way as 'it is easy to ...'.

Comment: @ tunny but they are " it is likely that ..." pattern. not " it is likely to .." pattern

Comment: @Murat. Ok, I read too superficially. Sorry. However, there is nothing there to say that 'it is unlikely to ..' is not possible.

Comment: It is definitely ok. The rule is a bit ambiguous

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18632/discussion-between-tunny-and-murat).

Comment: Murat, How does the link you provide support the false statement that one cannot use *it is + un/likely*? It is unlikely to give every conceivable example!

Comment: _My dog is likely to bite.  It is likely that my dog will bite.  I don't feel safe around my dog.  It is likely to bite._  (AmE)

Comment: @ADAM It is unlikely to appeal to a lot of people, your dog, I mean... I mean your mean dog: it is likely/bound to scare away people who try to pet it.

Comment: "Due" suggests a schedule or deadline.

Answer (score 2):

Let us look at all those options mentioned in your question. ***And*** we will see what **comes first** in *my* mind.

> Look at those dark clouds. It is likely to rain = It ought to rain today. It might be raining after some time.
>
> Look at those dark clouds. It is [bound](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bound_1) to rain - It is quite certain that it'll rain (It is *close* to *'likely'* but a bit more in degree of certainty). OALD's example: *It's bound to be sunny again tomorrow.*
>
> Look at those dark clouds. It is due to rain = The existence of those dark clouds is because of rain!

So, in the context defined, *likely* or *bound* work.

Comment: I don't fully agree with your last example, Maulik. I guess "it" here is what is called (by some) "an [existential pronoun](http://books.google.ru/books?id=hJRrsg-xiO8C&lpg=PA108&ots=0Gk-Tf-tC-&dq=%22it%20is%20raining%22%20existential&hl=ru&pg=PA108#v=onepage&q=%22it%20is%20raining%22%20existential&f=false)": it does not stand for any specific subject. See [this topic at ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-does-it-refer-to-in-its-raining). Or maybe it could be interpreted both ways.

Comment: @CopperKettle read the first sentence "...what comes ***first*** in my mind".

Answer (score 1):

Maulik and tunny are correct about their interpretations of "It is likely to rain", "It is bound to rain", and "It is due to rain."

Another option is "We're due for rain."  In this usage, rain is assumed to come more-or-less on a schedule.  Either it is now a time at which "we" expect rain, or the rain is "overdue".  Furthermore, "we" are under the influence of a "[gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy)" -- "we" assume that if the rain is "overdue", then rain is especially likely to happen soon.

There are several common situations where an American might say "We're due for rain."

- There has been a drought.  For example, "we" are in what is historically a wet season, but "we" have gone an unusual length of time without rain.
- The dry season historically ends soon, and "we" are expecting the wet season to start soon.
- A weather forecast (or an almanac) predicts rain soon (or in the recent past).
- Some places (during certain seasons) have rain at predictable times of day.  For example, many places have a brief thunderstorm in the middle of most summer afternoons.  Other places often have misty mornings.